# Finding an inverse in terms of an unknown in a matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $X =\begin{bmatrix} 6 &  a \\ -2 & -5\end{bmatrix}$ where $a$ is a constant and is not equal to 15.

I am trying to find $X^{-1}$ in terms of $a$. (So the inverse, in terms of $a$)

So I was thinking, by my current understanding, to swap the positions of $a$ and $d$ in this matrix so $6$ and $-5$ are in opposite positions. Then I need to put a negative sign in front of $b$ and $c$, so a becomes $-a$ and $-2$ becomes $+2$.

Then I need to divide everything by the determinant which is $(ad-bc)$.

Am I along the correct lines here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct! You will simply use the fact that for an invertible matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, $A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$, and more generally, $A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\det A}\operatorname{adj}(A)$.

Comment: Fantastic thanks for this further help.

So I can establish that the determinant of A (ad-bc) is 
-30 + 2a, or 2a - 30 to make it easier. 

So then, I need to do....

1 / 2a-30 x (-5 -a)
                  (2 6)

Comment: Determinant was established by doing -30 - -2a

Comment: @Icomefromalanddownunder I kindly refuse to answer this last question if you don't write it in correct LaTeX (especially, since I LaTeXified the question for you)

Comment: Okay that's fair play, how could I find a copy of the coding instructions?

Comment: @Icomefromalanddownunder Press edit to your own question, and you will probably see the code I used it. It is very intuitive so I am sure you will be able to improve your comment.

Comment: @Icomefromalanddownunder: When I was very new to using LaTeX (nearly 20 years ago, time flies, you know). Here's a short guide that I used: http://estudijas.lu.lv/pluginfile.php/14809/mod_page/content/16/instrukcijas/matematika_moodle/LaTeX_Symbols.pdf You can always right-click on any math equation, and choose Show Math As >>> TeX Commands, to see what the code is, and learn from there.